# The system reboots when I try to shut it down

Tags: shutdown, reboot, debian-jessie

When I try to shut down the system it just keeps on rebooting. I have tried both with the shutdown button (from the top right corner of the screen) and from the terminal by typing

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

What happens is that I get a very quick message that says "reboot ..." (I don't have time to read the rest) before the system shuts down. Then less than 5 seconds later it lights up again and the only way I can stop this is by pressing the power button.

I doubt that something might have happened while doing the usual update+upgrade (just before I started to have this problem) because I now have debian 8 instead of debian 7, which is what I originally installed. Does this make sense or is it just completely unrelated? In any case what can I do to fix the problem?

Comment: Try init 0 (zero) and let us know what happens

Comment: It seemed there is problem with grub boot loader so you can try to run the following command to update the grub so that the boot files would be recreated with that of entries exist.    sudo update-grub

Comment: init 0 does the same thing as anything else I have tried before: it reboots after few seconds.
sudo update-grub seems to change nothing...

Answer (score 0):

If it's Debian distribution, try "sutdown -hP now"
Otherwise look in your APIC settings and chain there to see if something there prevailing shutdown..

Comment: shutdown -hP now does the same thing as what I had tried before. I don't know where to find the APIC settings and what I should change then, I'm sorry!

Answer (score 0):

If its kinda urgent, then you might try to hold the power button for at least 5 seconds. Make sure that there are no open files and save any work before you try this.